# Optimazition MFs of Fuzzy inference by genetic algorithm

Tags: matlab, optimization, genetic-algorithm, fuzzy-logic

I am using **GA** to optimize the parameters of the membership functions in my fuzzy system.
I create a function for fitness:

```
function y = gafuzzy(x)
global FISsys
global allData
global realResult

FISsys = readfis('aCAess.fis'); 
allData = importdata('ab.mat');
realResult = importdata('ad.mat');

FISsys.input(1,1).mf(1,1).params = [x(1) x(2) x(3)];
FISsys.input(1,1).mf(1,2).params = [x(4) x(5) x(6)];

FISsys.input(1,2).mf(1,1).params = [x(7) x(8) x(9)];
FISsys.input(1,2).mf(1,2).params = [x(10) x(11) x(12)];

FISsys.output.mf(1,1).params = [x(13) x(14) x(15)];
FISsys.output.mf(1,2).params = [x(16) x(17) x(18)];

c = evalfis(allData,FISsys);
e=sum(abs(c-realResult)); 
y = e;

end
```

And A[15*18] matrix for linear inequalities is :

```
A = [1,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0;
0,1,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0;
0,0,0,1,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0;
0,0,0,0,1,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0;
0,0,0,0,0,0,1,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0;
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0;
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0;
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0;
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,-1,0,0,0,0;
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,-1,0,0,0;
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,-1,0;
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,-1;
0,1,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0;
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0;
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,-1,0]
```

and b[15*1] vector is:

```
b = [0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0]
```

but when I run **GA**, I get this error:
    Illegal parameters in fisTriangleMf() --> a > b

why?

Answer (score 3):

Generally, in the triangle MF the first number, here a (shows the left vertex) should be smaller than the second number, here b (the top vertex). So you can have a triangle MF like [-1 0 1] but it cannot be like [0 -1 1].

in your code, I assume sometimes you don't satisfy the inequality in one of those places:

```
[x(1) < x(2) < x(3)];
[x(4) < x(5) < x(6)];
[x(7) < x(8) < x(9)];
[x(10) < x(11) < x(12)];
....
```

if the program is randomizing these values, you can bound them in your code easily by checking and replacing, for instance:

```
if x(1) >= x(2)
     tmp = x(1);
     x(1) = x(2);
     x(2) = tmp;
end
```

Comment: Thanks NKN, but I set  linear inequalities correctly. Why its not working truely?

Comment: @OmidOmidi I didn't mean linear inequalities for the GA. check out how you are setting the x(i) values in your code. Those values should be taking care of.

Comment: (Constraints) : Linear inequalities of the form A*x ≤ b are specified by the matrix A and the vector b. (In optimtool). by add your code for each iteration need 10 sec.

Comment: How do you select x(i) for the MFs?

Comment: With this: FISsys.input(1,1).mf(1,2).params = [x(5) x(6) x(7)];

Comment: I know that man, where those numbers are coming from? (x(5),x(6),...)? Do you define them by yourself?

Comment: Dear NKN! This function is fitness function in GA and GA products X(i)s and put those in function automatically.

Comment: Then you need to check those values inside this function. Make sure that for example: x(5) < x(6) < x(7) and so on.

Comment: GA not perform constraints. @NKN, X(i)s are static and cannot modifying manually.

Comment: Omid Omidi, did you ever find a solution to this issue? I'm actually running into the same problem with the Matlab Fuzzy toolbox with constant MF parameters that are definitely ordered correctly.